# How to callout second time if first request gets timed out

Tags: integration, webservices, callout, external-services

I have been asked this question and I am looking for possible approaches for such scenario.

If I make an callout to an external service and if  don't receive any response and gets timed out and then If the entire callout process is repeated again then it will be marked as duplicate transactions, so what will be the most efficient way to make an callout again in such scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

That's something you may not be able to fix in Salesforce; you would need to check with your external service provider to determine an appropriate solution. The best you can do is to set the timeout to the maximum value (2 minutes) and hope for the best.

```
req.setTimeout(120000); // Wait as long as allowed
```